# Error when trying to use index command in a mongo database

Tags: mongodb

Anybody know why I get this error and how i can fix it!?

> db.people.ensureIndex({binkedin_id: 1})
>   {
>           "ok" : 0,
>           "errmsg" : "Index with name: binkedin_id_1 already exists with different options",
>           "code" : 85
>   }

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that the index you're creating already exists, but with different options (e.g. `unique: true`).

You can't change the options of an existing index, so you must first drop it and then re-create it if you want to change the options.

```
> db.people.dropIndex({binkedin_id: 1})
> db.people.ensureIndex({binkedin_id: 1})
```